# MODIS-Sphere to WGS84 coordinate system in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, modis-reprojection-tool, homolosine

I want to overlay two global raster datasets on land use which use different coordinate systems (MODIS-Sphere & WGS84) using ArcGIS Desktop. There seems to be no direct transformation option from MODIS-Sphere to WGS84. It seems to me that I would have to use a custom transformation. However, for that I would need some sort of transformations dialogue/script which I don't have. Or am I missing something?!

Does anyone have any idea on which steps to take?

The dataset I want to transform is http://urban.yale.edu/sites/default/files/data/setoguneralphutyra_uf.zip

Format: ESRI GRID
Projection: Goode's Homolosine Equal-Area Projection
Geographic Coordinate System: MODIS-Sphere

I want to transform this dataset so that it matches the other one (which uses GCS_WGS_1984 as spatial reference and D_WGS_1984 as datum)

Comment: In case anyone else is googlin': same dataset and same problem solved by:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170276/reprojecting-modis-sphere-esri-grid-file-to-wgs84-using-qgis-gdal

Answer (score 0):

There is a MODIS Reprojection Tool available from the USGS here:

https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool

You'll need to create an account to download it, but the registration seems painless.

Comment: The data I have is in ESRI Grid Format. The Reprojection tool needs input in .hdr or .hdf format. I added some additional information above. Unfortunately the HEG Tool is not working.

Answer (score 0):

use [Heg tools](http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGHome.html). You can save to tif and reproject to geographic coordinates. Also you can use batch.

Comment: Unfortunately the Heg Tool is not working on my computer. For whatever reason. I added some more information on my problem, do you have any other suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Try GDAL or ModisDownload (http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload)in r. Add a snapshot of the HegTool´s problem.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding Hegtool I contacted their Tec Support. I added the link to the dataset I'm working with in the question.